# Why does only shadow ray from light path node work in this material setup?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

This is initial setup. Red plane and green cube is a single object, red plane has flipped normal (directed inside cube). Another plane is half glossy half diffuse material:

[image]

It becomes interesting... Subtracting *Backface* from *Shadow ray* blocks shadow casting from red plane but alows shadowing from green cube (dark spot behind):

[image]

Then I tried with all other rays and such behaviour didn't occur. Every bounced ray is gone away except shadows:

[image]

I'm curious what is going on here, because I didn't expect Shadow ray to differ from others.

[image]

Comment: When you make the backfacing side of the cube transparent, the front and top facing sides still have a diffuse material and will cast a shadow.

Comment: You are right, post an answer if you want.